# Игнорирование движком сайта типа таблиц в БД MySql

Tags: mysql, типы

Постараюсь описать максимально понятно... 
В mysql есть две таблицы например mg_product и mg_productvariant 
в каждой из них есть столбец с названием srok и типом text

но при редактировании товара без вариантов (идет запись в таблицу mg_product) через админку и сохранение значение поля srok стирается как если бы в mysql был прописан тип столбца double или какой-то числовой.
а если у товара есть варианты (mg_productvariant) то значение поля srok записывается как положено и ничего не обрезается.

В чем может быть причина что в первом случае происходит игнорирование типа записи?

Comment: Как говорил Леонид Аркадьевич: "Код в студию!"

Comment: код чего? где скрипты работы cms на отправку этих данных в бд я хз

Comment: а тогда каким образом мы Вам должны помочь?.Проблема по всей видимости именно в коде и без него просто не о чем говорить.

Comment: просто не представляю как он должен выглядеть в моем случае. не могу найти что-то подходящее

Comment: В любом случае у Вас сейчас два выхода: найти участок кода, отвечающий за обработку данного запроса и приложить её к вопросу или просто отдать данную задачу на фриланс. Сообщество может Вам как помочь найти файл, так и помочь Вам разобраться с тем что не так с обработкой. Но сообщество не будет за Вас делать всю работу. Мы помогаем получить новые знания, разобраться в ошибках и можем рассказать Вам как их исправить, но для этого нужен предмет разговора(которого сейчас нет).SO не является биржей по бесплатному оказанию услуг. Здесь сообщество энтузиастов, которое хочет делиться своими знаниями.

Comment: Напишите путь, по которому находится форма и путь по которому данная форма обрабатывается(куда она отправляется после нажатия кнопки "Сохранить" или как она у вас называется)...Если бекенд примитивный, то 
 местоположение обработчиков запросов могут соответствовать пути в адресной строке. Например, запрос `http://domain.ru/admin/sales/index.php` может обрабатывать скрипт который лежит на сервере в папке `/{{document_root_path}}/admin/sales/index.php`

Comment: document_root_path - это корневая папка вебсайта. её расположение можно узнать из настроек сервера или с помощью переменной `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` в php скрипте

Comment: также запросы могут перенапрявляться с помощью настроек сервера. достаточно часто они лежат в файле `.htaccess` (нужно искать строки `RewriteRule`)

Comment: также сайт может иметь одну точку входа(так называемый FrontController) и принимать абсолютно все запросы и уже в зависимости от запросов перенаправлять их в соответствующие компоненты. В данном случае вся маршрутизация обрабатывается на уровне веб-приложения и нужно искать настройки маршрутизации вашего движка. В замисимости от используемых технологий они могут находиться в разных местах и по разному выглядеть

Answer (score 0):

Решилось тем что в файле models/product.php удалили несколько строк содержащих

```
if($array['srok']){ 
$array['srok'] = (double)str_replace(array(',',' '), array('.',''), $array['srok']); 
}else { 
$array['srok'] = 0;
```

Хотя выше над строками написано //исключает дублирование. Хоть по моему проблема решилась этим, но буду благодарен если поясните почему.

Comment: переместите это в вопрос

Comment: `(double)str_replace(array(',',' '), array('.',''), $array['srok']);` данный код берёт строку, заменяет в ней запятую на точку, а пробел на пустую строку и потом получившуюся строку пытается привести к типу double

Comment: если вам нужно хранить в базе форматированную строку, то да...данный код отменяет все форматирование и приводит строку  к типу double.